# how to increase waiting timeout from 30000 ms to 60000 ms of npm installing time in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-install

Since my internet connection is slow, i couldn't install packages from npm because of the fact that the npm returns with error as

> npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app (over 30000ms)

i hoped if i increase the waiting time to one minute or more the error will likely be fixed. And since i am on  ubuntu 18.04 i couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 17):

I don't know how similar to your problem. But I had trouble executing the following command after executing `npm install -g npm-check-updates`:

```sh
ncu -u
```

I just kept increasing the timeout after the command until it was fully executed.

```sh
ncu -u --timeout 100000
```

Answer (score 13):

add this to your `.npmrc` file:

```
timeout=60000
```

#### Edit:

Or as suggested in comments (by @Raine Revere), try instead the Doc's official: [fetch-timeout](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#fetch-timeout)

Comment: should be in your home folder: `/home/yourusername/.npmrc`. If you do `man npm` you can see that it also tried to load: `$HOME/.npmrc ` which is the same, and `Global Configs: The file found at ../etc/npmrc (from the node executable, by default this resolves to /usr/local/etc/npmrc) will be parsed if it is found.`

Comment: @Lioul if my answer solved your issue, please mark it as Accepted

Comment: this solved an timeout issue for me when publishing a package to npm.

Comment: I don't see the "timeout" parameter documented at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config. Please provide some resource backing your solution

Comment: @arc Experience mainly,  + debugging

Comment: @Ron +1 to your experience. It does accept timeout parameter (--timeout) too, with milliseconds as value. But mine fails complaining invalid argument as String

Comment: I recommend the official `fetch-timeout` option, as `timeout` does not appear to be part of the official api and may not always be supported: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#fetch-timeout

Answer (score 11):

Update npm configuration using:

```sh
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 60000 -g
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) and the [available options](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config).

Answer (score 8):

This answer is a bit late, but it's useful for future readers.

#### [As of NPM v7](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1151#issuecomment-618103078), **there is a `--fetch-timeout` option.**

When you run `npm install` add `--fetch-timeout`:

```sh
npm install --fetch-timeout=60000
```

There is also a [.npmrc configuration setting called `fetch-timeout`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#fetch-timeout). You can add the following to `~/.npmrc`.

```
fetch-timeout=60000
```

or run the following

```sh
npm config set fetch-timeout 60000
```

Answer (score 1):

Work with none of these solutions for windows. Then, I have added **--timeout** as a param to execute.

Ex:

```
npx npm-check-updates --timeout 200000
```