# Error creating react app in termux on android phone

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, termux

[image: Here is the error]

Occur this error while creating react app.

> npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT npm ERR! network Socket timeout npm
> ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity. npm
> ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network
> settings. npm ERR! network npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy,
> please make sure that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set
> properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2022-01-20T09_24_49_893Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

maybe try clearing your cache? Sometimes helps with problems I run into.

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm cache clean -- force
npm init
npm install -g create-react-app
npx create-react-app project-name --template all
```

in case the above doesnt work try

```
npm install yarn
yarn create react-app project-name
```

If you get error with this, create react app with a PC zip the file and send to your mobile unzip and CD to the file directory

Run

```
npm start
```

If you get permission denied means it's the end of the road for safe trials.
Means termix needs root permission to make react work

Answer (score 0):

Probably your internet connection, try running create react app on a fast connection or increase the [timeout second for npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61685270/how-to-increase-waiting-timeout-from-30000-ms-to-60000-ms-of-npm-installing-time)